# Table search on a filtered table?

Tags: search, filter, html-table, dropdown, tablefilter

I have a search function that searches a table with 3 columns. I have now implemented a dropdown that filters the table based on a place but when using the search function, it searches the whole table not the items that are left from the dropdown. Below is my function to filter the table but is there anything I can add to filter based on what is being shown and not what the table has as a whole?

Using HTML + JS

```
    function filterTable(event) {
    var filter = event.target.value;
    var rows = document.querySelector("#rosterTable tbody").rows;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = rows[i].cells[0].textContent;
        var fourthCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent;
        var fifthCol = rows[i].cells[4].textContent;

        if (firstCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fourthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fifthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, false);
```

Comment: What are you asking about. It is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, my issue is that I have a input search filter for a table but also a dropdown to filter the table by a location, the search looks at everything in the table and not what the dropdown filter shows. Did I explain it better or make it worse?

Comment: What language? What software? What environment? What are you using? What computers?